# PostgreSql Audit Table Trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have a trigger to generate logs but it is not very efficient because it ends up recording the entire row of the database.
I would like to know if there is a command to get the difference between **OLD** and **NEW**, so that I can write with a json **row_to_json(new)**.

Is there any way to write logs more compactly to the database?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "audit"."func_audit"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    f_table_name_audit constant TEXT    := tg_relname || '_audit';
    f_tg_op            constant TEXT    := SUBSTRING(tg_op, 1, 1);
    f_json             constant TEXT    := CASE WHEN f_tg_op = 'D' THEN row_to_json(old) ELSE row_to_json(new) END;
    is_new_row         constant BOOLEAN := CASE WHEN f_tg_op = 'D' THEN false ELSE true END;
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema' AND tablename = f_table_name_audit) THEN
        EXECUTE format(
            'create table if not exists audit.%I (
              id                      bigserial primary key,
              data_hora_utc           timestamp with time zone default now(),
              operacao                varchar(1),
              query                   text,
              pg_username             text,
              pg_application_name     text,                                             
              user_id                 int8, 
              row_log                 jsonb,
              is_new_row              boolean
            );', f_table_name_audit);
    END IF;
        
    EXECUTE format(
        'insert into audit.%I (operacao, query, row_log, is_new_row, user_id, pg_username, pg_application_name)
         values (%L, %L, %L, %L, %L, %L, %L);',
        f_table_name_audit,
        f_tg_op,
        current_query(),
        f_json,
        is_new_row,
        (SELECT current_setting('app.user_id', 't')),
        session_user,
        (SELECT current_setting('application_name')));
    RETURN null;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
```

Comment: See [Use a Postgres trigger to record the JSON of only the modified fields.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55875998/1995738)

Comment: worked perfectly as desired